# asynchronous websocket responses not being received

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, java-websocket

I built a publish/subscribe websocket using Tomcat 8.5.4, but I am having difficulty sending multiple asynchronous messages. Here's my endpoint implementation stripped down to its crude essence:

```
package com.example.websocket.server;

import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;


@ServerEndpoint("/repeater")
public class SocketEndpoint {

    /**
     * session ID(String) : Session
     */
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Session> activeConnections = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @OnMessage
    public void onData(InputStream data, Session session) {

        try {

            Byte newData = (byte)data.read();

            System.out.println("received data: " + newData);

            Enumeration<Session> connections = activeConnections.elements();

            ByteBuffer notification = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] { newData });

            int notificationCount = 0;

            while(connections.hasMoreElements() ) {
                Session connection = connections.nextElement();

                notificationCount++;

                connection.getAsyncRemote().sendBinary(notification, new SendHandler() {
                    @Override public void onResult(SendResult sendResult) {
                        System.out.println("getAsyncRemote().sendBinary() OK=" + sendResult.isOK());
                    }
                });

                //try {
                //    connection.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(notification);
                //} catch(IOException ioe) {
                //   System.err.println(ioe);
                //}
            }



            System.out.println("sent " + notificationCount + " notifications");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void myOnOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("session opened: " + session.getId());

        activeConnections.put(session.getId(), session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void myOnClose(CloseReason reason, Session session) {
        System.out.println("Closing a session: " + reason.getCloseCode());

        activeConnections.remove(session.getId());
    }
}
```

The problem I am encountering is that if there are multiple active connections, only one client will be notified in response to a 1-byte message being sent by one of the clients.
When I switch to using BasicRemote, all connected clients are notified as expected.

I would prefer to use AsyncRemote over BasicRemote in order to send notifications in the background while continuing to do work in onData().
It seems that the messages sent through AsyncRemote are being sent successfully, but the clients are not receiving them. Am I misunderstanding AsyncRemote?

I also wrote a JUnit test that confirms this behavior:

ServerTests.java

```
package com.example.websocket.server;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.authenticator.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl;
import org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.security.auth.message.config.AuthConfigFactory;
import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class ServerTests {

    private URI uri;

    private Tomcat tomcat;

    public URI getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        AuthConfigFactory.setFactory(new AuthConfigFactoryImpl());

        tomcat = new Tomcat();

        tomcat.setBaseDir("./target/server");

        final int port = 6000;

        tomcat.setPort(port);

        // No file system docBase required
        Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("", null);
        //add SocketEndpoint
        ctx.addApplicationListener(SocketEndpointSetup.class.getName());
        Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "default", new DefaultServlet());
        ctx.addServletMapping("/", "default");

        WebSocketContainer wsContainer =
                ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();

        tomcat.start();

        this.uri = new URI("ws://localhost:" + port + SocketEndpoint.class.getAnnotation(ServerEndpoint.class).value());

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        tomcat.stop();
        tomcat.destroy();
        tomcat = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotifications() throws Throwable {

        //client for sending message
        TesterMessageCountClient testClient1 = new TesterMessageCountClient(this.getUri());
        testClient1.connect();
        testClient1.listenForResponse();

        //clients for receiving notification messages
        TesterMessageCountClient testClient2 = new TesterMessageCountClient(this.getUri());
        testClient2.connect();
        testClient2.listenForResponse();
        TesterMessageCountClient testClient3 = new TesterMessageCountClient(this.getUri());
        testClient3.connect();
        testClient3.listenForResponse();

        final byte newData = 2;

        testClient1.getSession().getBasicRemote().sendBinary(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{newData}));

        ByteBuffer notification = testClient1.awaitResponse();

        assertThat(notification.get(0), is(newData));

        notification = testClient2.awaitResponse();

        assertThat(notification.get(0), is(newData));

        notification = testClient3.awaitResponse();

        assertThat(notification.get(0), is(newData));

        testClient1.disconnect();
        testClient2.disconnect();
        testClient3.disconnect();
    }

}
```

SocketEndpointSetup.java

```
package com.example.websocket.server;

import org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.Constants;
import org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsContextListener;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.websocket.DeploymentException;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer;

public class SocketEndpointSetup extends WsContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        super.contextInitialized(sce);
        ServerContainer sc =
                (ServerContainer) sce.getServletContext().getAttribute(
                        Constants.SERVER_CONTAINER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
        try {
            sc.addEndpoint(SocketEndpoint.class);
        } catch (DeploymentException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

TesterMessageCountClient.java

```
package com.example.websocket.server;

import org.junit.Assert;

import javax.websocket.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TesterMessageCountClient {

    public interface TesterEndpoint {
        void setLatch(CountDownLatch latch);
    }

    @ClientEndpoint
    public static class TesterAnnotatedEndpoint implements TesterEndpoint {

        private CountDownLatch latch = null;

        @Override
        public void setLatch(CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.latch = latch;
        }

        @OnClose
        public void onClose() {
            clearLatch();
        }

        @OnError
        public void onError(@SuppressWarnings("unused") Throwable throwable) {
            clearLatch();
        }

        private void clearLatch() {
            if (latch != null) {
                while (latch.getCount() > 0) {
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            }
        }

        @OnOpen
        public void onOpen(Session session) {
            session.getUserProperties().put("endpoint", this);
        }
    }


    public abstract static class BasicHandler<T>
            implements MessageHandler.Whole<T> {

        private final CountDownLatch latch;

        private final Queue<T> messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        public BasicHandler(CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.latch = latch;
        }

        public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
            return latch;
        }

        public Queue<T> getMessages() {
            return messages;
        }
    }

    public static class BasicBinary extends BasicHandler<ByteBuffer> {

        public BasicBinary(CountDownLatch latch) {
            super(latch);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(ByteBuffer message) {
            getMessages().add(message);
            if (getLatch() != null) {
                getLatch().countDown();
            }
        }
    }

    private final URI uri;

    private Session session;

    private BasicBinary handler;

    public TesterMessageCountClient(URI serverUri) {
        this.uri = serverUri;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return this.session;
    }

    public void connect() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("connect to " + uri);

        this.session = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer()
                .connectToServer(TesterMessageCountClient.TesterAnnotatedEndpoint.class, uri);
    }

    public void disconnect() throws IOException {
        this.session.close();
    }

    /**
     * Same as #setExpectedResponseCount(1);
     */
    public void listenForResponse() {
        setExpectedResponseCount(1);
    }

    /**
     * Call this to start listening for websocket messages. The messages can then be retreived using
     * #awaitResponses()
     * @param expectedResponseCount instruct awaitResponses() to block until this number of messages have been received
     */
    public void setExpectedResponseCount(int expectedResponseCount) {

        if(this.handler != null) {
            getSession().removeMessageHandler(this.handler);
        }

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(expectedResponseCount);
        TesterMessageCountClient.TesterEndpoint tep =
                (TesterMessageCountClient.TesterEndpoint) getSession().getUserProperties().get("endpoint");
        tep.setLatch(latch);

        this.handler = new TesterMessageCountClient.BasicBinary(latch);

        getSession().addMessageHandler(this.handler);
    }

    public ByteBuffer awaitResponse() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(awaitResponses().get(0).array());
    }

    public List<ByteBuffer> awaitResponses() throws InterruptedException {

        if(this.handler == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("call setExpectedResponseCount() first");
        }

        boolean latchResult = handler.getLatch().await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Assert.assertTrue(latchResult);

        List<ByteBuffer> responses = new ArrayList<>();
        Queue<ByteBuffer> messages = handler.getMessages();
        responses.addAll(messages);

        return responses;
    }
}
```